# What NodeJs does when too many requests performed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-request

For one of my tasks, I have to make too many requests to collect analytics. It's a search engine and for a valid reason, when somebody opens a page I must perform 6-8 requests to send different analytics.
I'm thinking to use "Promise.allSettled", but I don't know what will happen if it gets overloaded with too many requests. Right now our usage is low and on average I need to perform ~3 request per second(when requests are done is not important I just need to be sure all of them arrive to analytics server).
My question is, do NodeJs have some sort of garbage collector or anything else that will cause problems with sending all requests. Also if you have any better approaches please let me know, I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: "Too many" for what bottleneck? No, the garbage collector won't mind.

Comment: Is there any limitation for the requests? Like, 30 per second would hit a limit or something? What is the best method to make async requests?

Comment: The numbers you mention are extremely low. But if you are _ever_ worried just test & measure.

Comment: @TheD There's no limit in nodejs in that regard. You're only limited by CPU power, memory, and network throughput determined by the machine you're running on - but even low-cost machines will do a few hundred requests per second. What you *might* be affected by is a rate limit on the analytics APIs you are using - ask the respective service provider about those.